# Java Sequential Search not returning true on match

Tags: java, arrays, search, sequential

Building my own sequential search method and for some reason I can only get the int search to work, not the String.  The list being searched is built from a .csv file, and the file is read in one line at a time with each line containing all the data for one object.  A 2d array is pulled from that list of objects with just their name and ID, and the sequential search just searches those names & id's.  I ran it in the debugger and the array value being searched for does show up (in names[4][0]) but it doesn't return true, instead moving on to return false.  The int search returns true as it should in the right place.  Here's the sequentialsearch code:

```
    package Contributors;
        public class SequentialSearch {
            //search for name match
            static boolean contains(String[][] names, String nameSearched){
                for (String[] name : names) {
                    if (name[0].equalsIgnoreCase(nameSearched)) {
                    return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
     //search for ID match
     static boolean contains(String[][] names, int idSearched){
         for(int loop = 0; loop<names.length; loop++){
             if(Integer.parseInt(names[loop][1]) == idSearched){
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

Here is the class that builds the 2d array:

```
public class SearchArray {
String[][] nameSearch(List sortedList){
    String[][] sortedNames = new String[sortedList.size()][2];
    Contributor current;
    String currentName;
    String currentID;
    //loop to add each name and ID field to a 2d array
    for(int copy = 0; copy < sortedList.size(); copy++){
        current = (Contributor) sortedList.get(copy);
        currentName = current.getname();
        currentID = String.valueOf(current.getid());
        sortedNames[copy][0]=currentName;
        sortedNames[copy][1]=currentID;
    }
    return sortedNames;
    }
}
```

Here is the section of the main that calls the searches:

```
 //implement search
    String searchName = "Pipps, George";
    int searchID = 25;
    searchList = searchGrid.nameSearch(contributorList);
    if(SequentialSearch.contains(searchList, searchName)){
     System.out.println(searchName + " Found.");   
    }
    //search for contributor 25
    if(SequentialSearch.contains(searchList, searchID)){
        System.out.println("Contributor ID " + searchID + " found.");
    }
```

The very last System.out is printing (ID) but not the name.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Why use different `for` loops? Why not change the one that fails (String search) into the one that works (index search)? I.e., `for(String name[ ] : name)` seems to not work but `for(int loop = 0; loop<names.length; loop++)` does. I don't really see a problem with the former, but ... worth a try?

Comment: Have you tried substring test with both strings toLower or to Upper?

Comment: DSlomer - I did it both ways in case that made a difference - it didn't.

Comment: Fildor - Haven't used toLower or toUpper yet, I'll have to look them up

Comment: Please post a short, complete code sample that we can easily run on our side to see the same results. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are the strings in english language? Or may there be odd chars like a turquish "I"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can run this in the debugger, I guess you can also pause the program control right on `if (name[0].equalsIgnoreCase(nameSearched))` on the iteration where you expect it to result to true. Right there you can view if name[0] and nameSearched have really the values that you expect.

Comment: I did that, and to my eye, I couldn't see any difference between the 2 variables being compared.  That's why I don't know what's wrong.  It just goes on to the next line and returns false - do I need to add a break; or put the return false inside an if condition?

Comment: @MichaelChristopher Is it ok if you can a post a screenshot of that specific part where we can see the values of name[0] and nameSearched in the debugger. I'm thinking of the possibility that there is a very slight difference that passes your eye.